# Changed address

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoinj, bitcoin-wallet-app

My address has changed but I'm showing 0.00mbtc.  when I lookup the information on Blockchain it confirms 0.00 but then States the address has yet to be used on the network. I'm confused, please help.

Answer (score 1):

> #### Changed Address
>
> **My address has changed**

OK, your problem is that your address has *changed*.

#### "My address"

"My address" implies to me that you probably only have one address, otherwise you would probably have written "one of my addresses".

It also implies that the address is associated with a person not with a wallet or private-key etc. I expect that is probably just a loose way of using words but that phrasing might be a result of a misunderstanding - I can't tell how much experience you have. Don't take offence, I am trying to help but it may be I am pitching my help at the wrong level. You are new here, I can't tell how clued-up you are.

#### "Changed"

"Changed" means to me that an old address has disappeared and a different address has appeared in its place. This seems to me to be a possible misunderstanding of the way in which addresses are used in wallets.

---

What your question title means on the surface is that your wallet looked like this

On Monday:

```
,-----------.
|Address|BTC|
|-------|---|
|123... |500|
|       |   |
|       |   |
`-----------'
```

On Tuesday:

```
,-----------.
|Address|BTC|
|-------|---|
|987... |  0|
|       |   |
|       |   |
`-----------'
```

and you are puzzled why your address changed from 123... to 987...

---

Addresses in wallets don't really change, you can generate new addresses but the old address still exists. Typically you generate a new receiving address for each payment you want to receive.

Your wallet probably has a way of organising these addresses so that you can see the total unspent amount associated with just one address or one group of addresses.

---

> **when I lookup the information on Blockchain it confirms 0.00**

Then it is probably true.

Sometimes transactions take a long time (potentially a *very* long time, or forever) if the fee is too low.

> **I didn't receive any payment**

The sender could have made an error in entering the recipient address.

> **I've got 13 addresses in my wallet but no bitcoins.**

That might be normal if you have received BTC in 13 transactions and then spent them all.

---

Remember, the clearer the question, the better the answers. If this answer is useless to you, try editing your original question and explaining it like you would explain it to your grandmother, take time to plan out how you could organise the question to make it clear to her. Don't forget to sketch out the background to build an understanding of the situation. Don't omit details that may be crucial to an answer.

Just my BTC 0.00 worth.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean? Because I didn't receive any payment?... I've got 13 addresses in my wallet but no bitcoins

Comment: @JT: I edited my answer to clarify. It now seems likely I misunderstood what you were saying. If so I'll delete this answer as it is unlikely to be helpful to you and anyone else other than to illustrate the need to take care when writing an answer to clearly explain what has happened and what you need help with. Screenshots and actual addresses would probably help people to help you.

Comment: No I'm a newbie and I'm just seriously confused.  You are actually helping me thank you.  I have another question regarding this.  I actually never sent any transaction at all but my addresses are changing?  I'm using bitcoin for developers wallet on my phone.

Comment: Are you using [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.schildbach.wallet)?

Comment: Yes I'm using the wallet previously mentioned